# Was the phrase "Zawsze in Love" generated using Google Translate?

Tags: nisekoi

In chapter 216 of the manga, it was revealed that the title "Zawsze in Love" was actually a mistranslation from an translation program. It didn't specify whether it was done using Google Translate or any other translation program.

The first volume of Nisekoi was published in 2011. At that year, Google Translate was not as good as it is now. I don't know the quality of Google Translate's Japanese to Polish translation in 2011 since I don't use Polish and never learned it, so there was no reason for me to translate from Japanese to Polish. My question is, has the author ever mentioned what translation program he used so that he ended up with the phrase "Zawsze in Love"? Or did he generate the phrase himself and used translation program as an excuse in the story?

Note that I'm not asking about the meaning of "Zawsze in Love", which already explained [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9560/what-meaning-does-the-phrase-zawsze-in-love-have). I'm asking about it's origin.

Comment: [every](https://gyazo.com/dc3f6fb6fc6a3fa6d11fb30c1830e1e4), [translation](https://gyazo.com/e31345c16a4d1f9527a44aeb99b04b5d), [differs](https://gyazo.com/77b995f817a045fe1e770e8c0d6c6993), [abit](https://gyazo.com/42dc997e696398e25076f2649c2584c6)

Comment: The manga shows that it was translated from Japanese to Polish and the program shows the Polish translation as Zawsze in Love

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing, inputting [恋を永遠に (forever love) in Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_c#ja/pl/%E6%81%8B%E3%82%92%E6%B0%B8%E9%81%A0%E3%81%AB) returned the exact phrase "*Zawsze In Love*".

[image: Google Translate's result]

Other, like [永遠の愛](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_c#ja/pl/%E6%B0%B8%E9%81%A0%E3%81%AE%E6%84%9B) returned a whole phrase in English, "forever Love", but some didn't: [愛を永遠に](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_c#ja/pl/%E6%84%9B%E3%82%92%E6%B0%B8%E9%81%A0%E3%81%AB), [永遠の恋](https://translate.google.com/?source=gtx_c#ja/pl/%E6%B0%B8%E9%81%A0%E3%81%AE%E6%81%8B).

In the end, this can't be a definitive proof that the author used Google Translate or whether Google Translate gave this result at that time, since now anyone can suggest a translation and skew the result.

**Update as of 2018**: as stated before, Google Translate's results may change:

- **恋を永遠に ("Zawsze In Love")** and 愛を永遠に ("forever Love") were replaced with "[Miłość na zawsze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR5rR.png)"

making them more consistent.

---

Further reading: [How Google Translate works - Latin.SE](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4352/1625)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when she wanted to name the story book, she wanted to translate it in English, but she translated it to Polish instead by mistake. However, she was still attracted to the Polish version, and hence she named it "Zawsze in Love".

So, it's not any translation error mentioned. It's actually an error done by the author by choosing a different language by mistake.

Comment: It'd be best if you could provide references for this, because the Polish-English mixed translation is still weird (understandably, it's a translation tool that is bound to any mistake)